# Найти последнюю наибольшую запись в неформат поле

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с полем **number**:

```
ID| Number
1 | SK/100/05/2020
2 | SK/101/05/2020
3 | SK/02/01/2021
4 | SK/03/01/2021
5 | SK/04/01/2021
6 | SK/34/02/2021
7 | SK/35/02/2021
8 | SK/36/02/2021
9 | SK/37/02/2021
10 | SK/30/02/2021
```

Последняя фактическая запись в таблице *SK/30/02/2021*.

Нужно составить запрос, который бы возвращал последнюю наибольшую запись с учетом месяца и года, т.е. такая последняя считается **SK/37/02/2021**. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Рекомендую добавить в структуру таблицы виртуальное вычисляемое поле, индексировать его и использовать в выражении сортировки.

Answer (score 2):

извлекайте компоненты и сортируйте

```
ORDER BY  substring(v,-4) DESC, substring(v, -7,2) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

но если хотите, чтобы это быстро работало, храните дату отдельно и индекс по полю